# Return outside method error

Tags: java, methods, return

```
boolean openingboard;
{   
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color color3 = new Color(108, 25, 85);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 770);
    while(true)
    {
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    search: for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++)
        {
        for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                if(image.getRGB(x, y) == color3.getRGB())
                {
                    System.out.println("About to finish and return true");
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("About to finish and return false");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error is:
java:71: return outside method

return true

^

i don't know what this is happening please help!

Comment: Is all this code inside a method?

Comment: inside the method openingboard? yea not the main method though should i post that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your comment response above, I am going to make the educated guess that you believe that

```
boolean openingboard;
{
    return true;
}
```

defines a Java method called `openingboard`.  This isn't the case.  Java follows the C paradigm of requiring you to specify your parameters in parentheses, regardless of whether you have any parameters or not.  So, the method

```
boolean openingboard() {
    return true;
}
```

is a valid Java method (assuming it is inside some class), as is a version of `openingboard` with much more code between the curly braces.

That said, I'm going to pass along a few friendly pointers on Java style:

- Java (and indeed most higher-level language) programmers tend to frown on "forever" loops such as `while (true)`, since those loops make it much harder to determine when the loop actually stops.
- There is no need for the label `search` in the code, and labels are even more discouraged than forever loops are.

So, I would recommend rewriting your code to look something like

```
private boolean openingboard() {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Color color3 = new Color(108, 25, 85);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 770);
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
    for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(image.getRGB(x, y) == color3.getRGB())
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

assuming of course that you prefer a debugger to trace prints.

Comment: I have not heard much commentary - positive nor negative - regarding labels.  I would have thought them benign.  So why are they frowned upon?

Comment: @emory Unless you are using labels for a nested break or continue, there is absolutely no value to a label that a comment doesn't provide.  As a result, a comment conforms much better to convention.  A label is OK for nested break/continue statements, but unnecessary for any other reason.  I would classify a Java label in with a C goto: it's useful to improve readability in a very limited set of circumstances, but don't use it outside that set.

Comment: @emory Using labels are pretty much the same thing as goto statements which are [considered harmful](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF).

Answer (score 5):

Proper methods look like: `boolean openingboard ( )`

not like `boolean openingboard;`

The parenthesis are not optional.

The way you have it:  openingboard is a field.  There is a init block with a Robot and a color and some for loops nested inside of each other.  Inside one of the for loops is a return which is not allowed in an init block.